# IN asp.net sql command Assigning ID to a row using an insert statement from one table into another

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I've been trying to insert data from one row using multiple query and second one query (select id from aspnerusers) to get them and assign by first query last row.how it's here is my code snippets

```
 string filepath = Server.MapPath(" ~/Audio/datamail.mp3");
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
        br.Close();
        fs.Close();

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into [dbo].[Bookmarks](id,Name,audio,userid) values (1,'hollywood',@audio,@userid) ";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@audio", System.Data.SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", "SELECT ID  from aspnetuserss");

        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

just like one to many relationship.some error in { cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", "SELECT ID  from aspnetuserss");} how to solve it??? any one can help me.

Comment: Did you post this to ask a question?

Comment: yeah i'm asking a question

Comment: What's the error say?  You should separate out the parameter building into different lines instead of using .AddWithValue. You will be able to find your problem easier that way I believe.